# EOF Error, Java & Derby Database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

HI I'm creating a calendar using derby database. I've created and inserted into the database, however when printing; it throws an EOF error.
Any advice welcomed, This is the method in question.

```
public void show() {
    try {
        ResultSet results = stm.executeQuery("select * from Users");
        while (results.next()) {
             //print result???
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace:

> Syntax error: Encountered "" at line 1, column 167.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation

problem: 
    The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Here is the setup

```
     public void populate() {
            try {
        stm.execute( "insert into Users values (User_ID, User_FirstName, User_LastName , AdminFlag, UserNamex, Passwordx"
                +                             "(12565, 'Elliot','Green','True' ,'elliot2','1234')");
```

--

```
     public void createTable() {
    try {
        stm.execute("drop table User"); // May fail
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStack();}

    String sql1 = "create table Users ( "
            + "  User_ID          Integer,"
            + "  User_FirstName   Varchar(50),    "
            + "  User_LastName    Varchar(50), " 
            + "  AdminFlag        Boolean, "
            + "  UserNamex        Varchar(50),  "   
            + "  Passwordx        Varchar(100) )";



    try
    {
        stm.execute("drop table Users");
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    try {
        System.out.println("SQL sql1");
        stm.execute(sql1);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(-1); // Give up 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please change this line: `System.err.println(e.getMessage());` by this one: `e.printStackTrace()`, run the code again, copy the relevant stacktrace and edit the question to provide us the stacktrace.

Comment: Now you have compilation errors and your code cannot be executed.

Comment: You're trying to run uncompilable code -- never do that. So which line is the offending line? Which line does your compiler tell you is broken?

Comment: The compiler tells me there are two errors. both in Show(). No idea what's going on.

Comment: The compiler should tell you ***exactly which lines are involved***. Please share this with us.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GB2su9aQ  problems with SQL statement:
Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 167.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void)

 at ci236.jdbc.DBAccess.show(DBAccess.java:174)
 at ci236.jdbc.DBAccess.main(DBAccess.java:13)

Comment: So it turns out the offending line that causes the compilation error is only on your pastebin.  The code you've added to your question doesn't contain the offending line, so anyone reading your question wouldn't have found the problem.  I take it you didn't intend to mislead us by deliberately hiding the problematic line?  Either way, this is a poorly-asked question. -1

Answer (score 1):

The offending line from your pastebin is this:

```
    System.err.println(e.printStackTrace());
```

`e.printStackTrace()` is a `void` method, in that it doesn't return anything.  You cannot pass the result of this method to `System.err.println(...)`  as it doesn't make sense: there is nothing to print.

You should write

```
    e.printStackTrace();
```

instead.